# Async task not running continuously

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an **async task** retrieving data from **twitter api**, and a listener to run once the **async task** completes, can anyone tell me why the **async task** only runs once? i.e. it only returns the cursor once, i tried using a do while loop to surround the **async task** and it just runs in an infinite loop. (It's supposed to stop when cursor value is 0, with starting value -1).

Below is where i called the method with **async task**

```
loadTwitterFriends(new cursorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onFollowReceived(long cursor) {
            if(cursor == 0) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(cursor),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else{
                Log.e("Cursor failure", String.valueOf(getCursor()));
            }
        }
    });
```

Method with async task

```
private void loadTwitterFriends(final cursorListener listener) {
    MyTwitterApiClient myTwitterApiClient = new MyTwitterApiClient(twitterSession);
        myTwitterApiClient.getCustomTwitterService().list(loggedUserTwitterId, getCursor()).enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<FriendsResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FriendsResponseModel> call, Response<FriendsResponseModel> response) {
                Log.e("onResponselol", response.toString());
                twitterFriends = fetchResults(response);
                getActivity().setTitle(String.valueOf(twitterFriends.size()) + " Following");


                setCursor(fetchResults3(response));
                Log.e("onResponseFlwing", "Cursor:" + getCursor());


                Log.e("onResponse", "twitterfriends:" + twitterFriends.size());




                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (getCursor() == 0){
                    listener.onFollowReceived(getCursor());
                    return;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FriendsResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                listener.onFollowReceived(1);
                Log.e("onFailure", t.toString());
            }

        });
}

private List<TwitterFriends> fetchResults(Response<FriendsResponseModel> response) {
    FriendsResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
    return responseModel.getResults();
}
private long fetchResults3(Response<FriendsResponseModel> response) {
    FriendsResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
    Log.e("lol",String.valueOf(responseModel.getNextCursor()));
    return responseModel.getNextCursor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because `AsyncTasks` are designed like that

From official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a
>   second execution is attempted.)

So if you need to cycle that you should create everytime new `AsyncTask`.

Actually `AsyncTask` is based on simple java `Thread` and `Thread` [cannot be started twice too](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

It throws `IllegalThreadStateException` if started twice

And by the way we cannot start Thread twice because there are a lot of problems with it, for example:

- If thread is started twice we have 2 threads which use 1 runnable object so we have huge concurrency problems.
- What thread id will have thread object after second start
- etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But what do u mean by starting a new AsyncTask, can u explain how i can do that? do u mean i should call the method that has the async task several times? I did that and it gave me the same infinite loop